# Does anyone know a good program for adjusting confidence intervals for FDR under the BH proceedure?

Tags: python, r

I have estimated confidence intervals (CI) for a dataset of Tajima'D D values using bootstrapping to derive a null distribution. I would like to adjust these CI's to account for false discovery rate (FDR) using the BY procedure, as this allows for data points to be non-independent. I can already do this for the individual p-values associated with each data point in the R package p.adjust. However, I would prefer to modify the confidence interval for the dataset as a whole, however, rather than for each individual p-value. (Doing so would make it much quicker to delineate significant and non-significant values on a graph).

Does anyone know of a program that can do this (preferably written in R or Python)?

BY FDR is detailed in:
Benjamini and Yekutieli (2005). False Discovery Rate - Adjust Multiple Confidence Intervals for Selected parameters. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 100 (469).

Benjamini and Yekutieli (2001). The Control of False Discovery Rate in Multiple Testing Under Dependency. The Annuals of Statistics, 29, 1165-1188

Comment: Question better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Look at `?p.adjust` in the R `stats` package (installed and loaded by default). There are a variety of adjustment methods including one named "BY" which has the same 2001 citation by the authors you refer to. You will I suppose need to check that the method is the same in the 2005 and 2001 papers.

Since the p-value can be "inverted" to yield a CDF location or a standard error-like value, you should be able to use the readily available code in that function that shows on your console session with:

```
p.adjust
```

... and then cobble together a CI for whatever sample statistic you are massaging.

Comment: p.adjust will modify individual p-values, but does not seem to have an option for adjusting cut-off values...

Comment: "Adjusting cut-off values" is a) not terribly specific in the absence of code and b) not something that was mentioned in the question. You should post an example to make your problem specification more concrete.